# Physically accurate camera simulation software

Tags: simulation, camera

Is there any physically accurate rendering software that can reproduce real-world visual artifacts such as [chromatic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration), [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare), [rolling shutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter), etc. without post-processing?

Comment: When you say "without post-processing", do you mean that you want this to happen in-camera?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user has not been seen since they day that they joined almost 3 years ago, I will post this and if gets a single upvote this question will no longer be bumped to the home page.

I say that there is an inherent contradiction. The use wants an app (or would not be posting here), but wants it done "without post-processing", which seems to imply "without an app".

Answer: this question is the polar opposite of a  logical tautology and cannot be answered.